# pandas: ValueError when assigning DataFrame entries using index due to a change since v 0.13.1

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, indexing

I will begin with a concrete example:

The following works on;

- pandas version:   0.13.1
- numpy version:    1.8.0 b

  but not on;
- pandas version:   0.14.0
- numpy version:    1.8.1

`import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4), index=np.random.rand(10))
A.loc[A.index] = A.loc[A.index]`

In pandas newer version it results in:

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

I did not figure out what was the change from 0.13.1 -> 0.14.0 and **how should I modify the code**.

For those wondering what is the application:
This is useful when A is a large DataFrame that needs to be updated iteratively, each time only by a sub-frame.
So the real-life code resembles more:

`while something:
   ...
   A.loc[B.index] = A.loc[B.index].add(B, fill_value=0)
   ...`

Where the index of `B` is a subset of the index of `A`

Comment: You are using a ``Float64Index``. Are you really sure this is what you want? easy enough to ``A = A.reset_index()`` then your operations will work normally. ``Float64Index`` is a very special use-case (this is a bug, see here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7586)

Comment: I may be missing something here... If I will `reset_index` I will not be able to use it as labels, right? Then I loose the `A.loc[B.index] = A.loc[B.index].add(B, fill_value=0)` type functionality. In my particular case the index results from timestamps differences which I needed to convert to `Float64` due to another motivation. Clearly I could bypass the situation somehow but it worked great previously (pandas 0.13.1). Is there a reason why this does not work any more? Is there a more "pandas-onic" way to do this?